# Conditions in Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a simple Linux shell script which checks the status of services running and if any process is not running it will display the name of the process which is not running.

I have tried below and stuck now in else statement. 
What I want to output an else statement is the name of variable out of the 4 displayed which is having a non zero value.

The output should be like below if RUNWRAPPERSTATUS and EKYCSTATUS are non zero.

```
There is some while starting RUNWRAPPER AND EKYC . Kindly verify
```

Actual Code starts here:

```
ps -aef | grep -i NGEjbClient
RUNWRAPPERSTATUS=$(echo $?)

ps -aef | grep -i startSMS
RUNSTATUS=(echo $?)

ps -aef | grep -i DirectoryService
DISSTATUS=(echo $?)

ps -aef | grep -i EKYCUploadWorkitem
EKYCSTATUS=(echo $?)


if [ $RUNWRAPPERSTATUS -eq 0 ] && [ $RUNSTATUS -eq 0 ] && [ $DISSTATUS -eq 0 ]  && [ $EKYCSTATUS -eq 0 ]

then
    echo "Jboss Services and App Services started"
```

Comment: `var=(echo $?)` is an array assignment, maybe you want `$(` ? All `$RUNSTATUS` `$DISSTATUS` `$EKYCSTATUS` will be equal to `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script that showcases what you could do:

```
SERVICES="NGEjbClient startSMS DirectoryService EKYCUploadWorkitem"
for service in $SERVICES
do
    if ! pgrep $service
    then
        echo "$service is not running. Please verify"
    fi
done
```

NOTES:

- use `pgrep` to search in process names
- use a loop to avoid duplicate code if possible.

Comment: pgrep is not working in my case as NGEjbClient is not the script name but argument to the script. ps -aef | grep NGEjbClient works and gives output

Comment: ! pgrep $service  -- what does this mean

Comment: `pgrep` : search a process whose name contains the string.

Comment: @rizwan, the `!` is to negate the exit status: `if ! COMMAND; then A; else B; fi` executes `A` if `COMMAND` "failed", and `B` if it "succeeded".

Comment: @rizwan `pgrep` exists specifically as a cleaner replacement for the `ps | grep someprocess | grep -v grep` kluge (see my answer). If you have it available on your system, it's a better tool for this job.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Thanks

Comment: ! pgrep $service  will this be like [ ! pgrep $service  ]

Comment: no because `[]` needs an operator (like *equals* or *>=* or ...)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than collecting exit statuses in separate variables, I'd make an array of failed service names. I'd also just loop over the services, rather than writing an explicit separate test for each one.

But there's another problem: the `ps | grep something` pattern tends to find the `grep` command, which gives false positives. One way to avoid this is to add a `grep -v grep` to the pipeline.

If you don't want to print the found process entry, add the `-q` option to the last `grep` in the pipe. Important: it must be the *last* one or it won't work.

```
failedServices=()    # This creates an empty array

for service in NGEjbClient startSMS DirectoryService EKYCUploadWorkitem; do
    ps -aef | grep -i "$service" | grep -vq grep ||    # Remove "q" option to print matches
        failedServices+=("$service")    # +=() appends to the array
done

if (( ${#failedServices[@]} == 0 )); then    # This tests the number of elements in the array
    echo "Jboss Services and App Services started"
else
    echo "Some service(s) have not started:" "${failedServices[@]}"
fi
```

Comment: `grep -q` to avoid needless output ? otherwise nice solution.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Good idea; I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @GordonDavisson grep -q string always give exit status of 0 even if no string found

Comment: @rizwan That shouldn't be the case. Note that `grep -qv string` should exit with nonzero status only if no lines *not* matching "string" are in the input (i.e. if either intput's empty, or *every* line contains something matching "string"). This can be a bit confusing. It's possible you have a version of `grep` that doesn't handle the `-qv` combination properly; try swapping the order, i.e.: `ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep -iq "$service"`